# How to split TaiPy GUI multi-page application where each page has its own file?

Tags: python, taipy

I want to simplify my multi-page Taipy GUI application by creating one Python file per page. Each new file should contain the Taipy Markdown page format and the custom Python code to manipulate variables used in the page.

The basic setup with one **main**.py file is explained here:
https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/getting_started/getting-started-gui/step_07/ReadMe/

How would I organize my Taipy multi-page application with one Python file per page?

What I tried initially was to create one Python file per page and move all custom code to set/manipulate variables and the page's Markdown format in the respective file.

The issue is that Taipy is unable to read variables or functions defined in the page's Python file. Only the page format is read. My next idea would be to set all variables in the application's **main**.py file, but that will bloat it up quite a lot in my view.

Comment: Hey nonome (or maybe noname XD), Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple Scripts to divide your Markdown and Python code according to pages.

Taipy GUI  has a concept of Scope ([Documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/binding/#scope-for-variable-binding)). If you wrap your Markdown in the `Markdown(...)` object, Taipy can retrieve the variables and functions you have defined in these scripts. These values and functions has a Scope relative to your page. If you want global variables or functions (used in multiple pages), you must import them into your *main.py*.

Here is a little example of an application using this Scope concept:

*page_1.py*:

*value* and the `run()` function have a Scope relative to the *page_1*. They can't be used on other pages (except if we import them into the *main.py*).

```py
from taipy.gui import Markdown

value = 10

page_1_md = Markdown("""
<|{value}|slider|>

<|Push|button|on_action=run|>
""")

def run(state):
    print("run")
```

*main.py*:

I import the Markdown object of *page_1* to create my application.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
from page_1 import page_1_md 

pages = {
   "/":"<|navbar|>",
   "Page-1":page_1_md 
}

Gui(pages=pages).run()
```